# Движение объекта до стены, Unity2D

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, move

Я хочу двигать кубик, пока он не коснется стены при нажатии на шифт. Впринципе это работает, но если нажимать шифт прямо у стены, то кубик все равно проходит сквозь ее. Как это можно поправить?

```
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    axisX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    axisY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        Move();
    if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(axisX * speed, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 3);
    }
}


void Move()
{
    if (!gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.Intersects(wall[0].GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds))
    {
        gameObject.transform.position += new Vector3(axisX, axisY, 0);
    }
    else {
        gameObject.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

}